# CTE expression SELECT * INTO table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following query which I want to put inside a table

```
with cte (domain, ip_addr, time_col) as
(
select 'Google',101,'2020-03-31 14:55:37'
UNION select 'Google',101,'2020-03-31 14:56:12'
union select 'Facebook',101,'2020-03-31 14:57:36'
union select 'Amazon',101,'2020-03-31 14:57:45'
)

select
domain,
ip_addr,
time_col,
sum(switches) over (partition by ip_addr) -1
from (
select *,
case when lag (domain) over (partition by ip_addr order by time_col) = domain then 0 else 1 end as switches
    
from cte
) t
```

when I run the following code to create a table out of this CTE I get errors

```
select * into [dbo].[Test] from (
with cte (domain, ip_addr, time_col) as
(
select 'Google',101,'2020-03-31 14:55:37'
UNION select 'Google',101,'2020-03-31 14:56:12'
union select 'Facebook',101,'2020-03-31 14:57:36'
union select 'Amazon',101,'2020-03-31 14:57:45'
)

select
domain,
ip_addr,
time_col,
sum(switches) over (partition by ip_addr) -1
from (
select *,
case when lag (domain) over (partition by ip_addr order by time_col) = domain then 0 else 1 end as switches
    
from cte
) t ) A
```

I get three errors:

1. Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'WITH'
2. Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'with'. If this statement is a common table expression, an xmlnamespaces clause or a change tracking context clause,  the previous statement must be terminated with a semicolon.
3. Incorrect syntax near ')'.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You can't select from a `with` you select after it, as in your first query. Just add `into [dbo].[Test]` as part of your first select.

Answer (score 3):

The CTE defines a query for use in the select statement.

You need to use `select into` as you would with just the `select` you already have working. All columns must also have a name or alias:

```
with cte (domain, ip_addr, time_col) as
(
select 'Google',101,'2020-03-31 14:55:37'
union select 'Google',101,'2020-03-31 14:56:12'
union select 'Facebook',101,'2020-03-31 14:57:36'
union select 'Amazon',101,'2020-03-31 14:57:45'
)

select domain, ip_addr, time_col, 
  Sum(switches) over (partition by ip_addr) -1 as ColumnName
into dbo.Test  --<< INTO goes here
from (
    select *,
    case when Lag (domain) over (partition by ip_addr order by time_col) = domain 
        then 0 else 1
    end as switches
from cte
) t;
```